# What's the proper typing for a React Testing Library wrapper in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

So i have something like this from kent c dodd's library that is super useful

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import {render as rtlRender} from '@testing-library/react'
import {ThemeProvider} from 'components/theme'

function render(ui, {theme = 'light', ...options} = {}) {
  const Wrapper = ({children}) => (
    <ThemeProvider initialTheme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
  )
  return rtlRender(ui, {wrapper: Wrapper, ...options})
}

export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override React Testing Library's render with our own
export {render}
```

i'm having trouble converting it to typescript though. any thoughts on what i need to fine tune below?

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { ReactNode } from 'react'
import {render as rtlRender} from '@testing-library/react'
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from 'react-query'

interface WrapperProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

const queryClient = new QueryClient();
function render(ui, {client = queryClient, ...options} = {}) {
  const Wrapper = ({children}: WrapperProps) => (
    <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
      {children}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
  return rtlRender(ui, {wrapper: Wrapper, ...options})
}

export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override React Testing Library's render with our own
export {render}
```

i'm getting the below about typing on the wrapper:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(ui: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>, options: RenderOptions<typeof import("path/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries"), HTMLElement>): RenderResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '({ children }: WrapperProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
      Type '({ children }: WrapperProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
        Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'WrapperProps'.
            Property 'children' is optional in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type 'WrapperProps'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(ui: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>, options?: Omit<RenderOptions<typeof import("path/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries"), HTMLElement>, "queries">): RenderResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '({ children }: WrapperProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
      Type '({ children }: WrapperProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(41, 3): The expected type comes from property 'wrapper' which is declared here on type 'RenderOptions<typeof import("path/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries"), HTMLElement>'
index.d.ts(41, 3): The expected type comes from property 'wrapper' which is declared here on type 'Omit<RenderOptions<typeof import("path/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries"), HTMLElement>, "queries">'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from 'react-query'

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const render = (ui: ReactElement, { client = queryClient, ...options } = {}) =>
    rtlRender(ui, {
        wrapper: ({ children }) => (
            <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
                {children}
            </QueryClientProvider>
        ), ...options
    });

export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override React Testing Library's render with our own
export { render }
```

Ideally you shouldn't be exporting the entirety of testing library just to replace the render function, you could just create your own wrapper and use it together with testing library. But still, that code above should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can type your render function as this

```
import { render as testingRender, RenderOptions } from "@testing-library/react";

// ...

const render = (
  ui: React.ReactElement,
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, "queries">,
) => {
  return testingRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...options });
};
```

Just so you know, my wrapper it's defined as yours

```
type WrapperProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const Wrapper = ({ children }: WrapperProps) => {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          // ...
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: I've chosen to separate `render` function from `Wrapper` component, but that's not required at all. It was just simpler for me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think ts is infering `Wrapper` as `JSX.Element`, but the `rtlRender` expects a "FunctionComponent".

So, you can `Wrapper: FunctionComponent` or by using its shortcut `Wrapper: FC`

Also, there is not need for the `WrapperProps` interface, because children is spected.

```
import * as React from 'react'

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query'

import {render as rtlRender} from '@testing-library/react'

const queryClient = new QueryClient();
function render(ui, {client = queryClient, ...options} = {}) {
  const Wrapper: React.FC = ({children}) => (
    <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
      {children}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
  return rtlRender(ui, {wrapper: Wrapper, ...options})
}

export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override React Testing Library's render with our own
export {render}
```